# Разделение массива на подмассивы в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть вот такой файл:

```
200 "profi.ru" "17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300" "213.55.176.147" "-" "0.034" 8648 "GET /b/?Chekhlov HTTP/1.1" "https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-" "80" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251" "en-us" "-" "-" "-" "0.032" "127.0.0.1:8080" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"

200 "profi.ru" "17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300" "213.55.176.149" "-" "0.004" 6044 "GET /style.css?v=40 HTTP/1.1" "http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-" "80" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "text/css" "en-us" "-" "-" "-" "0.004" "127.0.0.1:8080" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"

200 "profi.ru" "17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300" "213.55.176.149" "-" "0.003" 1479 "GET /js.js?v=2 HTTP/1.1" "http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-" "80" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "application/javascript" "en-us" "-" "-" "-" "0.004" "127.0.0.1:8080" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"

200 "profi.ru" "17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300" "213.55.176.149" "-" "0.004" 6355 "GET /b/txt/img/Chekhlov.jpg HTTP/1.1" "http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-" "80" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "image/jpeg" "en-us" "-" "-" "-" "0.004" "127.0.0.1:8080" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"

200 "spb.profi.ru" "17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300" "213.55.176.149" "-" "0.003" 491 "GET /i/sn/vk_24g.png HTTP/1.1" "http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-" "80" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "image/png" "en-us" "-" "-" "-" "0.004" "127.0.0.1:8080" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"

200 "profi.ru" "17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300" "213.55.176.149" "-" "0.003" 311 "GET /i/sn/fb_24g.png HTTP/1.1" "http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-" "80" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "image/png" "en-us" "-" "-" "-" "0.000" "127.0.0.1:8080" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"
```

Я считываю файл в питон:

```py
f = open('access.log')
data = f.read().replace(' - - ', ' ').split()
```

Затем у меня получается список, мне нужно разделить этот список построчно(т.е. каждая запись лог файла - отдельная строка). Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядит как csv:

```
import csv

with open('access.log') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row:
            print(row)
```

Результат:

```
['200', 'profi.ru', '17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300', '213.55.176.147', '-', '0.034', '8648', 'GET /b/?Chekhlov HTTP/1.1', 'https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1', '-', '80', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251', 'en-us', '-', '-', '-', '0.032', '127.0.0.1:8080', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['200', 'profi.ru', '17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300', '213.55.176.149', '-', '0.004', '6044', 'GET /style.css?v=40 HTTP/1.1', 'http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1', '-', '80', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'text/css', 'en-us', '-', '-', '-', '0.004', '127.0.0.1:8080', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['200', 'profi.ru', '17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300', '213.55.176.149', '-', '0.003', '1479', 'GET /js.js?v=2 HTTP/1.1', 'http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1', '-', '80', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'application/javascript', 'en-us', '-', '-', '-', '0.004', '127.0.0.1:8080', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['200', 'profi.ru', '17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300', '213.55.176.149', '-', '0.004', '6355', 'GET /b/txt/img/Chekhlov.jpg HTTP/1.1', 'http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1', '-', '80', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'image/jpeg', 'en-us', '-', '-', '-', '0.004', '127.0.0.1:8080', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['200', 'spb.profi.ru', '17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300', '213.55.176.149', '-', '0.003', '491', 'GET /i/sn/vk_24g.png HTTP/1.1', 'http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1', '-', '80', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'image/png', 'en-us', '-', '-', '-', '0.004', '127.0.0.1:8080', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['200', 'profi.ru', '17/Apr/2019:14:33:26 +0300', '213.55.176.149', '-', '0.003', '311', 'GET /i/sn/fb_24g.png HTTP/1.1', 'http://profi.ru/b/?Chekhlov', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1', '-', '80', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'image/png', 'en-us', '-', '-', '-', '0.000', '127.0.0.1:8080', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
```